# Rename data using grep?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I am searching for all the instances of DEFAULT_DEV_PATH using grep

```
grep -r -n --color "DEFAULT_DEV_PATH" *
```

What I want to do is rename every occurance of DEFAULT_DEV_PATH with just DEV_PATH using command line.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like sed might be a better tool for the job...

```
sed -i 's/DEFAULT_DEV_PATH/DEV_PATH/g' *
```

And if you wanted to do it recursively like you are doing with grep, you could combine with find:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/DEFAULT_DEV_PATH/DEV_PATH/g' {} \;
```

Per the comments, you may need to provide an argument to the `-i` option if you are not using a GNU extension.

Comment: Its throwing this error: sed: 1: "LICENSE": invalid command code L

Comment: Okay it worked. Thank you so much I really appreciate it. Just a minor tweak if i may suggest,

-i needs an extension so i did sed -i old 's/DEFAULT_DEV_PATH/DEV_PATH/g' *

It makes a copy of the old file with that extension

Comment: @joel The -i flag without argument is a GNU extension. Other sees, like the BSD flavor on OS X, need to be called with `-i''` to achieve the same result.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. Sorry, GNU extensions are all I have been using.